# send cookie for an input and send to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I want to send a cookie for an input and send it to my database but send me empty
here create the cookie and send for one viewn

```
require_once('../modelo/modelobusqueda.php');
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        # code...
    $cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
    setcookie('cedula',$cedula, time()+3600);
    $obj = new busqueda();
    if (isset($_POST['enviar']))
    {
    $value= $obj->busquedaexp();
    }
}

< form action="" method="POST" id="miform">

< label>Cedula:</label></br>

< input type="text" id="cedula" name="cedula" maxlength="8" class="form-control" < ?php echo "value='".$_COOKIE["cedula"]."'"; ?> disabled></br>
```

**Below is the error message I received:**

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'cedula' cannot be null

Comment: where is your mysql? I see no insert or update. cant check your error without your Code.  Please post your php with your mysql.

Comment: controller require_once('../modelo/modelopersona.php');
 $obj = new persona();
 if(isset($_POST['enviar1']))
 {
  $obj->registrarpersona();
   }

Answer (score 0):

the model
class persona

{

private $conex;

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->conex = new conexion();
}
```

public function registrarpersona()

```
{

    try {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO expediente (cedula, nombre, apellido, telefono, descripcion, direccion, fecha_nac, sexo, id_parroquia) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    $obj = $this->conex->prepare($sql);
    $obj->bindValue(1,$_POST['cedula'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $obj->bindValue(2,$_POST['nombre'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $obj->bindValue(3,$_POST['apellido'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $obj->bindValue(4,$_POST['telefono'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $obj->bindValue(5,$_POST['descripcion'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $obj->bindValue(6,$_POST['direccion'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $obj->bindValue(7,$_POST['fecha_nac'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $obj->bindValue(8,$_POST['sexo'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $obj->bindValue(9,$_POST['id_parroquia'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $obj->execute();    
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error Al Registrar Expediente: " .$e->getMessage();
    }
```